# How Do I Give My C++ Application The File Path Of The File Clicked To Open Said Application

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I have an application that uses custom file types, and I have associated these file types with my application (Windows File System). When I double click the file my application opens, but I would like to be able to pass in the data from the file.

I had hoped that the file path would have been sent to main, but no such luck. Whenever I open the application by clicking on a file 'argc' reads '0'. Opening the application normally give 'argc' as '1'.

Is there a way to pass in the file path used to open the application?

Comment: Not sure why people vote this "off topic". It's part of the program installation, which is definitely on topic.

Comment: If the file association is done properly, then it *should* work, and you should see the file that is being used in the parameter list. Things I can think of that would prevent this is some form of single-instance code that doesn't have a way of passing the filename to the already running program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't know *a priori* how your program should be started. Perhaps it's `d:\path\to\exe\foo.exe --no-spash --input-file "C:\what you\clicked.foofile"`. That's why you put in a registry entry, to tell Windows.

Now there's of course one part of that string above which you don't know up front, and that's of course `"C:\what you\clicked.foofile"`. In the registry entry, use `"%1"` and Windows will substitute the actual path. Don't forget the `" "` since paths can contain spaces, and else your path will end up in `argv[1]` *and* `argv[2]`. That was especially common in XP, with `My Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

The path of the file calling will be stored in "char* argv[]" as either "argv[0]" or "argv[1]" (sorry for not remembering exactly, my C++ is a little rusty) . "int argc" simply lists how many elements exist in "char* argv[]"

Comment: I was hoping for that to be the case, but however I have this set up the application does not get any arguments passed to it when I double-click my files. 'argc' is '0' and 'argv[0]' is empty.

Comment: That is the only way I have heard of it being done directly.. The only other way i can think of doing it is to write a small launcher application that does take arguments and sends the file name to the main process. Not a very eloquent solution however. I would highly suggest you write your program to accept arguments.